# error: filesystem unknown grub rescue in virtual machine

Tags: grubrescue

When I tried to load Ubuntu 18.04 on my virtual machine (Oracle Virtualbox) I get message:

```
error: unknown filesystem 
grub rescue>
```

These are the results of command ls:

```
grub rescue>ls
(hd0)(hd0,msdos1)

grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos1) 
 unknown filesystem

grub rescue>ls (hd0)
 unknown filesystem
```

What can I do?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! There isn't enough detail in this question for it to be answerable. I'd recommend that you [edit] it to include the exact steps required to reproduce the problem. For example, what Ubuntu version? How did you install it? Your question will be better received if you also show some evidence of what you've already reasearched/tried to resolve the issue. See [ask].

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the commands. It looks like you forgot to separate input and output, and I think there are some words missing.